# UTF8Encode different result on different systems (UTF8Decode)

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-7

I ran into an interesting anomaly. I receive a WideString text via RPC, which I need to convert to ANSIString and check the signature in the text against the hash of the text.

On English based Windows (the signature generating server is also English based) it works fine, but on other base language systems (so far it has happened in Russian and Turkish) there are discrepancies.

I have made a simple little test sample to filter out the problematic parts and I noticed that on different systems the UTF8Encode function returns different values for the Unicode characters (the Latin characters are of course fine).

The results are as follows:

```
System language       | English                  | Russian
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unicode               | Baйкальская              | Baйкальская
Character codes (ORD) | 1041 1072 1081 1072 1083 | 1041 1072 1081 1072 1083
                      | 1100 1089 1082 1072 1103 | 1100 1089 1082 1072 1103
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UTF8Encode            | Ð'Ð°Ð¹ÐºÐ°Ð "ÑŒÑÑÑÐºÐ°Ñ  | Р'Р°Р№РєР°Р "СЊСЃРєР°СЏ
Character codes (ORD) | 208 8216 208 176 208 185 | 1056 8216 1056 176 1056 8470
                      | 208 186 208 176 208 187  | 1056 1108 1056 176 1056 187
                      | 209 338 209 129 208 186  | 1057 1034 1057 1027 1056 1108
                      | 208 176 209 143          | 1056 176 1057 1039
```

The UTF8 encoded characters above were generated using the UTF8Encode function in System, but I also tried the UnicodeToUTF8 function in the Tnt library. Tnt has the option to set the codepage, but if you set a codepage other than UTF8 (or UTF7) the encode does not work.

Whatever I tried, in all cases the above results came out on both systems (or sometimes I got back an empty string in both places when playing with the codepage).

Google searches have not yielded any results either. Although there were some issues with unicode behaving differently on different systems, the only place where there was a solution was to set the encoding of the file containing the unicode.

One more piece of info: the resulting string does not contain a BOM, and the signing program is not homemade, so I cannot modify it.

Any ideas? Suggestion?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Edit:**

For numeric values greater than 255... I display the unicode and the encoded result in the same Tnt (Unicode) memo, and the unicode component converts the ANSI to widestring, that's why these numbers come out. I have now converted the display to a plain ANSI memo so that it really shows ANSI characters. Below is the result (bold highlights the change):

```
System language       | English                       | Russian
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unicode               | Baйкальская                   | Baйкальская
Character codes (ORD) | 1041 1072 1081 1082 1072 1083 | 1041 1072 1081 1082 1072 1083
                      | 1100 1089 1082 1072 1103      | 1100 1089 1082 1072 1103
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UTF8Encode            | Ð'Ð°Ð¹ÐºÐ°Ð°Ð "ÑŒÑÐºÐ°Ñ       | Ð'Ð°Ð¹ÐºÐ°Ð°Ð "ÑŒÑÐºÐ°Ñ
Character codes (ORD) | 208 145 208 176 208 185       | 208 145 208 176 208 185
                      | 208 186 208 176 208 187       | 208 186 208 176 208 187
                      | 209 140 209 129 208 186       | 209 140 209 129 208 186
                      | 208 176 209 143               | 208 176 209 143
```

But it's not just the numbers that are under 255 (and they now match perfectly on both sides)... in the Russian system, the text starting with P appeared visually in the ANSI memo, but when I copied and pasted it in the English system, the text starting with Ð appeared. The same in reverse, if I copy it from here to the memo of the program running on the Russian system, the one beginning with P appears (paste to the russian notepad shows text starting with Ð).

**Edit 2:**

Well, back to basics... After it turned out that UTF8Encode produced exactly the same result, I went ahead and looked at the signature validator part of the signature validator function. I wrote out the part to be signed and saw that instead of unicode characters, there are just question marks (in ANSI memo of course, in Unicode of course the original unicode text is displayed).

I'm working in Delphi 7, but the core system can be used in Delphi RAD too, the signature validator is set up with compile directives to handle the difference between the two IDE separately for the string type. Under Delphi 7 it encodes first (I thought this was the problem so far), then decodes back to WideString before validating (obviously it doesn't do these under RAD).

I had a thought and deleted UTF8Decode from the Delphi 7 code fragment... After that the Encode version of the string appeared, but the signature is not valid. Normal, since it was signed on the decoded text.

And here comes the difference... In English the Russian text is unicode, so after the Encode/Decode the original unicode text comes back. However, in Russian, the original unicode Russian text after Encode/Decode picks up the corresponding value between 128 and 255 based on the Russian code page. Which is no longer the original unicode value.

In any case, I need to modify the system so that it does not Encode/Decode, and the problem will be solved.

Comment: Well the UTF8/Russian is wrong, as it is not UTF-*8* (they are 16-bit characters). So start by finding out why that is...

Comment: And the UTF-16 in the upper left corner (10 UTF-16 code points) is not a complete representation of the Russian "Baйкальская" (11 chars).

Comment: HeartWare! You're right, i missed a 1082 on 4th position. Just checked result are same, and copied English to Russian.

Comment: `UTF8Encode()` and other UTF-8 encoding functions do not behave differently based on the system language, so the problem has to be elsewhere. Maybe the `WideString` is wrong to begin with? Where exactly is it coming from? And why are you using `WideString` instead of `UnicodeString`? Which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: I use WideString, because i use Delphi 7. Sorry, I forgot to mention it.

Comment: @Needback: You should consider upgrading. Delphi 7 is almost 20 years old.

Comment: @Needback that is a major detail to omit, because Unicode support in such an old version was VERY basic. And IIRC, the UTF8 handling back then was badly broken (it didn't support Unicode code points >= U+10000 at all. That was fixed in D2009). So, you should forget the RTL's UTF-8 functions and use the Win32  `MultiByteToWideChar()` and `WideCharToMultiByte()` functions directly instead.

Comment: Strings don't contain BOMs - files do...

Answer (score 1):

There's something with your implementation/interpretation. Your UTF-8 is not UTF-8 (as can be seen by the values being 16-bit and not 8-bit in most cases).

EDIT: A later comment showed that the OP is using Delphi7, so the below doesn't apply. However, it applies to all Unicode versions of Delphi from D2009 onward...

Try this code on a Button `OnClick` event:

```pascal
PROCEDURE TForm102.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  VAR
    S,M : STRING;
    U   : UTF8String;
    C   : CHAR;
    UC  : UTF8Char;

  BEGIN
    S:='Baйкальская'; // Note "Ba" at the beginning is ASCII characters - is that correct?
    U:=S;
    M:='UTF-16:';
    FOR C IN S DO M:=M+' '+IntToHex(Ord(C),4);
    M:=M+#13#10'UTF-8:';
    FOR UC IN U DO M:=M+' '+IntToHex(Ord(UC),2);
    MessageDlg(M,TMsgDlgType.mtInformation,[mbOK],0)
  END;
```

On my PC, it displays this result:

```
UTF-16: 0042 0061 0439 043A 0430 043B 044C 0441 043A 0430 044F
UTF-8: 42 61 D0 B9 D0 BA D0 B0 D0 BB D1 8C D1 81 D0 BA D0 B0 D1 8F
```

Which is the correct UTF-8 encoding of the UTF-16 string. There's no such thing as code pages in UTF-8 (or UTF-16), AFAIK, so you're barking up the wrong tree.

The easiest way to obtain a UTF-8 string from a UTF-16 string is simply to declare a variable of type `UTF8String` and use assignment from a `UnicodeString` or `WideString`. Delphi does the conversion for you.

Just remember that UTF-16 uses 16-bit characters, and UTF-8 uses 8-bit characters.  Don't try to use `AnsiString` - that one is CodePage-dependant and will screw you over if you try to use it to store a UTF-8 string. If you MUST use an 8-bit string, use `RawByteString` instead, or - even better - forego strings altogether and use a `TBytes` instead:

```pascal
VAR
  UTF8 : TBytes;
  S    : STRING;
  ...
  UTF8:=TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(S);
  ...
```

Comment: "*Delphi does the conversion for you.*" - actually no, because the OP is using D7, which although it has `UTF8String`, it wasnt a *true* UTF-8 string yet, just asn alias for `AnsiString`. It didn't become a native string type with full RTL support until D2009.

Comment: Which I added to the reply while you were editing it.